# mmap and mutex usage

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading

I am new to Linux and so I have a few questions about using mmap and threads.

Is it so that in Linux a mutex will cause a context switch?  I did Google and some people say yes and others no.  Therefore is a critical section better? I will use only one process.

So, I am user side and I have mmaped some HW registers.  I have code which is basically like:

```
setRegisterBits(  offset, fromBit, toBit )
{
   ReadRegister()
   ModifyRegister()
   WriteRegister()

}
```

Many threads could access the same mmap and so I need this function to be atomic.  What would a Linux programmer suggest?

Comment: "Will a mutex cause a context switch?" That's a weird question. A mutex is just an object. Does an `int` cause a context switch? What about a closing brace, or a macro?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it so that in Linux a mutex will cause a context switch?

Linux mutex is implemented using [futex](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/futex.7.html):

> Futex operation is entirely user space for the non-contended case. The kernel is involved only to arbitrate the contended case.  As any sane design will strive for non-contention, futexes are also optimized for this situation.

In other words, when a mutex is locked the thread context switches to kernel, gets put in futex wait queue and de-scheduled off the CPU and hence stops making forward progress (blocks, another context switch).

---

> Therefore is a critical section better?

On Windows [`CRITICAL_SECTION`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms682530(v=vs.85).aspx) is essentially an in-process mutex.

On Linux, there are `pthread_mutex_t` (http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_mutex_init.html) and [std::mutex](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex) which is a wrapper over `pthread_mutex_t`. `pthread_mutex_t` is universal, it works the same way whether it is used for in-process or out-of-process (between threads of different processes) synchronization. `std::mutex` does not provide out-of-process functionality though.

More generally though, [critical section is a block of code which only one thread can enter at one time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_section).

There is also [`pthread_spinlock_t`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_spin_destroy.html) on Linux, which can also be used for in-process or out-of-process synchronization. It does not de-schedule the process, however, care must be taken to lock it only for shortest periods of time possible, so that the waiting threads do not waste the CPU busy-spinning on it.

---

> I am user side and I have mmaped some HW registers. I have code which is basically like [...] Many threads could access the same mmap and so I need this function to be atomic. What would a Linux programmer suggest?

It is many producers, single consumer scenario. The answer depends on your optimization objective, the expected level of contention, and the time it takes to execute `setRegisterBits` and whether it can block.

If `setRegisterBits` blocks then non-blocking synchronization primitives would be a bad choice because this would waste CPU cycles of other threads for no good reason while waiting for this thread to unblock and exit `setRegisterBits` critical section.

The default choice to start with would be `pthread_mutex_t`. Benchmark how it works for your workloads.

The scheduling delay on modern Linux on modern x86_64 hardware is an order of 3-10 micro-seconds, i.e. this is the time it takes a thread to wake up after the mutex it has been waiting for was released. If you are minimizing latency and `setRegisterBits` executes under half of that wake up delay and does not block using `pthread_spinlock_t` may be warranted, but again you need to benchmark.

A better option may be to have one worker thread that ever calls `setRegisterBits`. That thread waits on a thread-safe queue for commands. Many threads can post commands to that queue. There are quite a few off-the-shelf thread-safe queues you may like to consider, for example [`tbb::concurrent_bounded_queue`](http://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/docs/help/reference/containers_overview/concurrent_bounded_queue_cls.htm) or [`boost::lockfree::queue`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/lockfree.html). The benefit of this pattern is that it minimizes latency of producer threads. The queue gets only blocked while posting and receiving an inter-thread message and this can be done in an extremely optimized way. This method is optimal if invoking `setRegisterBits` takes longer than sending and receiving an inter-thread message or it may block.

---

For benchmarking locking there is [Intel VTune Locks and Waits Analysis](https://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/doclib/iss/2013/amplifier/lin/ug_docs/GUID-53C69CDC-8BAC-48EF-BC3E-0A420B7FE054.htm):

> While Concurrency analysis helps identify where your application is not parallel, Locks and Waits analysis helps identify the cause of ineffective processor utilization. One of the most common problems is threads waiting too long on synchronization objects (locks). Performance suffers when waits occur while cores are under-utilized.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I wanted and more.  I now have information to move forward.  All of my functions are blocking.

Answer (score 2):

There are two levels of context switches: The switch that is performed when you call into the kernel (by doing a syscall) and the switch that is done by the kernel to give a core to another process. The first one is relatively inexpensive and is generally not termed "context switch", the second one is the real context switch and can be very expensive.

That said, whenever the kernel takes the CPU away from your process, you get the big expensive variant. And that happens when you try to lock a mutex that's already locked.

When the mutex is not locked and its implementation uses a syscall to lock it, you get the relatively inexpensive switch into kernel space and back.

If your mutex has a userspace fast path like the futex, you have neither a context switch nor a kernel switch when the mutex is uncontended.

If you use a spinlock, no context switch or kernel switch is needed, *if and only if all processes have a CPU for their own*. If that is not the case, a spinlock would waste tons of time, and it would not be able to avoid the context switches (which will take place by the kernel preempting processes after up to 10 milliseconds of spinning to given other processes a chance to run).

Answer (score 0):

If a task tries to enter a critical section by grabbing a mutex, and the critical section is locked (another task ownes the mutex) the task will have to wait for the resource.

This means the task that is "locked out" gives up the CPU (if it is ***unblocking***) and another task on the read queue will run. The task waiting for the mutex will be on another queue waiting for the mutex along with any other tasks waiting for the mutex.

So, in Linux a thread trying to grab a mutex may indirectly cause a context switch, on the CPU between threads.